# save_and_open_page doesn't open a new browser

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I just setup a new project. When I use `save_and_open_page` in my cucumber steps it doesn't open a browser. What am I forgetting? Any gem I forgot to include? Any config I missed?

Comment: oops! `Sorry, you need to install launchy ('gem install launchy') and make sure it's available to open pages with 'save_and_open_page'.`